# JSON data to a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

How to get JSON data to a table in HTML

I am getting back JSON data and trying to append to a table as below but it is not working

```
  <table>
<thead>
        <tr>SerialNo</tr>
        <tr>Name</tr>
    </thead>
<tbody id="dynamicTbody"></tbody>
</table>


$.getJSON(url, function (json) {

    ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE 
    for (var i = 0; i < json.records.length; i++) {

 $('#dynamicTbody').append('<tr><td>'+json.records[i].SerNo.SerialNo+'</td><td>'+json.records[i].name.Name+'</td></tr>')
}}
```

have edited this since my question was not clear enough

Comment: What does the JSON text look like? You should be able to post a runnable snipped without the `$.getJSON` and just `var json = {...}`.

Comment: `/* Headings for the table` is a syntax error, as is `/ FINALLY...`. Single line comments start with `//`, mulitline comments must be closed: `/* ... */`. The *for* block isn't closed, there is no *JSONdata* element in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const records = [
  {SerialNo: 1, name: 'User 1'},
  {SerialNo: 2, name: 'User 2'},
  {SerialNo: 3, name: 'User 3'},
  {SerialNo: 4, name: 'User 4'},
  {SerialNo: 5, name: 'User 5'},
];

const table = document.createElement('TABLE');

records.forEach(record => {
  let row = table.insertRow();
  row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(record.SerialNo));
  row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(record.name));
});

document.getElementById('JSONdata').appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="JSONdata"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that-I am currently doing what you suggested-

Comment: However that is not what I want..sorry my bad that the question is not clear...I have amended the question

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. This is essentially just a refactoring of the OPs code. It's not clear why the OP's code doesn't work, so it's not really possible to provide a good answer yet.